# Create a protobuf extension in openRTB with Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a extension in a openRTB protobuf request, but I don't know how.
As they say in their docs (https://github.com/google/openrtb/wiki) I should can do something like that:

```
BidRequest request = BidRequest.newBuilder()
    // ... add Imp, etc.
    .addDevice(Device.newBuilder()
        .setModel("Nexus 85")
        // ... other standard Device fields
        .setGeo(Geo.newBuilder()
            .setCountry("USA")
            .setCity("Newer York")
            .zetZip("102879")
            .setExtension(SpaceAdsExt.planet, "Mars")))
    .build();
```

In this example, they set a custom extension named SpaceAdsExt.planet. How I can implement an extension like this?

Answer (score 1):

The `BidRequest` proto has certain ranges of tag numbers reserved for extensions. According to its definition [here](http://openrtb/openrtb-core/src/main/protobuf/openrtb.proto), tags 200 to 999 and 2000 to 9999 are reserved for extension by exchanges and projects. You will need to create a `.proto` file that extends `BidRequest` by defining an extension for one of these tag numbers. That would look something like this:

```
extend com.google.openrtb.BidRequest {
  optional MyExtension my_extension = 2111;
}
```

For more detail, see the protocol buffer documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions). One thing to beware of is that you must choose a unique tag number for your extension--if someone else defines an extension with the same tag number that you chose, then data corruption could result. I would recommend checking with the OpenRTB developers to see if they have a convention for ensuring uniqueness of extension numbers.